# Convert NER dataset to spaCy formt for Arabic text

Tags: nlp, spacy, arabic, named-entity-recognition

I tried to convert a NER dataset written in English to spaCy format, everything worked fine but when I tried to do the same thing with a dataset written in Arabic:

```
!python -m spacy convert -c iob -s -n 10 -b nlp /gdrive/MyDrive/LearningSpacy/SimpleNER-Dataset.txt .
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
    setup_cli()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/_util.py", line 71, in setup_cli
    command(prog_name=COMMAND)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/typer/main.py", line 532, in wrapper
    return callback(**use_params)  # type: ignore
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/convert.py", line 74, in convert_cli
    converter = _get_converter(msg, converter, input_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/cli/convert.py", line 257, in _get_converter
    input_data = file_.read()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byt
```

This is how the SimpleNER-Dataset.txt looks like:

[image]

Comment: It sounds like the file isn't UTF-8. Can you open the file in Python outside of spaCy? Just using `open` and `read`?

Comment: @polm23 you're correct, it's not  UTF-8, but I can open it and read it normally, I converted it to UTF-8 and it solved the problem.